# sosl exception on searching with one character

Tags: exception, sosl, code-coverage

On doing a sosl search with just one character search parameter, I am getting an exception. To overcome this i have used custom error message in the catch block.However I am unable to cover the catch block in the test class.
The functionality of the code is working fine.

```
CONTROLLER METHOD:
    public void Query(){
        try{
                        iserrorfound = false;

                        if (sSearchWord != null && sSearchWord.trim() != '')    
                        {     
                            List < List < sObject >> SearchResult = search.query('FIND \'' + string.escapeSingleQuotes(sSearchWord) + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Object__c (ID,name,field1__c,field2__c '+ addlFunc() +' )');
                            belts = SearchResult[0];
                            SetController= new ApexPages.StandardSetController(SearchResult[0]);
                        } 
                        else    
                        {
                            //Logic if search parameter is null/empty
                        }
                        SetController.setPageSize(10);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
                {

                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please enter at least two characters');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    iserrorfound = true;
                }

    }


TEST CLASS:

    test.starttest()
    //
     Inst.sSearchWord = 'p';
     Inst.Query();
    test.stoptest()
```

Comment: you could also test for the size of the search string before entering the SOSL query and then the catch block becomes less interesting

Answer (score 0):

SOSL is awkward to test given that you have to use [Test.setFixedSearchResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setFixedSearchResults) and there isn't any built-in testing mechanism to help with your case.

All you can do is add code to allow the testing (generally something that should only be done as a last resort). For example:

```
@TestVisible private Boolean throwSearchException = false;

public void Query(){
    try {
        ...
        if (throwSearchException) throw new SearchException('Fake');
        ...
    } catch (SearchException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then in the test case for this error condition

```
...
YourController inst = new YourController();
inst.throwSearchException = true;
...
```

and assert the `ApexPages.Message` that you get.